I'm have having issues fetching max value of a column when I try to combine it with data from a different table
I'm have having issues fetching max value of a column when I try to combine it with data from a different table.
I can run this query just fine to get the maximum value of a column
select
max(instance)
from
pace_masterdbo.generic_journal_details
However when I try to run the below query- SQL states that "p"."max"; is an invalid identifier
SELECT o.name as NAME, p.max(instance) as Max_Instance
from v$database o, pace_masterdbo.generic_journal_details p
any idea on how to fix my query that is failing?
Tried to run SELECT o.name as NAME, p.max(instance)as Max_Instance
from v$database o, pace_masterdbo.generic_journal_details p
and I was expected to get below results
NAME               Max_INSTANCE
ALLP345            2156456
